# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'rawinsert' was called on null

Tags: flutter

Getting this error when I try to login into the app I created. Also this error only comes for Iphone or Ipad. It works fine for ios simulators, android emulators and devices. Rawinsert usage in code:

```
Future<int> insertUser(UserModel sqluser) async {
Database db = await database;
return await db.rawInsert(
    'INSERT INTO $loginTable($colEmailId, $colPassword ,$colloginDateTime) VALUES(?,?,?)',
    [
      sqluser.email,
      sqluser.password,
      DateTime.now().toUtc().toString(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What is `database` ? Can you show the declaration of that variable ?

Comment: static Database  _database;

Comment: So you didn't initialised the _database right? So it will be null. Also why you used await there ?